# iOS Google Drive SDK Get Sub folder ID

Tags: ios, google-drive-api

I have the following code, which lists out the files in the root, but does not list any of the sub folders in the root:

```
NSString *parentId = @"root";

GTLQueryDrive *queryDrive = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesList];
queryDrive.q = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"'%@' in parents and trashed=false", parentId];

[self.driveService executeQuery:queryDrive completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,GTLDriveFileList *files,NSError *error)
{
     if (error == nil)
     {
         NSLog(@"Number of files: %i", [files.items count]);

         NSLog(@"Have results");
         // Iterate over files.items array
         for(GTLDriveFile *file in files)
         {
             NSLog(@"File Title:  %@ | ID: %@",file.title, file.identifier);
         }
     }
     else
     {
         NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);
     }
 }];
```

This lists out the 7 files I have in the folder, but at the same level as the 7 files, I have a sub folder.

For example:

root->file1
root->file2
...etc 
all come back

But root->MyFolder does not get listed in the result set.

Any ideas?

Comment: Okay so I found a solution.  The sub folder I was trying to get the id for was created manually.  I tried creating a sub folder in code and now that sub folder shows up with the id.  So, by creating the folder in code, I was able to do what I needed to do.

Comment: For existing subfolders, you can enumerate `mimeType = application/vnd.google-apps.folder` for all `GTLDriveFile`s with `parentID = 'root'` - for each apply a subquery of type... `GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForChildrenListWithFolderId:file.identifier];`, then `[<GTLDriveService instance> executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, GTLDriveChildList *driveFolderChildren, NSError *error) {}]`.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check how you've authenticated your app. If you authenticate with only your app's files as your scope, you will not see other files and folders created outside of your app.

When you authenticate like this:

```
self.gDriveAuthenticationViewController = GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch(scope:kGTLAuthScopeDrive,
        clientID:clientId,
        clientSecret:clientSecret,
        keychainItemName:keychainName,
        delegate:self,
        finishedSelector:"viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:")
```

Use scope:kGTLAuthScopeDrive instead of kGTLAuthScopeDriveFile